# How to add background, and border as svg images to a rect element

Tags: javascript, css, image, svg, d3.js

I have the following code which draws a rect element on the svg box with blue background and pink boarder.  I would like to change the blue background with an .svg image and the pink boarder with another .svg image.

```
 //how to put the border around the SVG element
   var borderRect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','rect');
   borderRect.setAttribute("id", "bRect");
   borderRect.setAttribute("width", bb.width);
   borderRect.setAttribute("height", newVboxH);
   borderRect.setAttribute("x", bb.x);
   borderRect.setAttribute("y", bb.y);
   borderRect.setAttribute("style","fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9");
```

Comment: create patterns, put images in the patterns and then fill ad stroke the rect with the patterns.

Comment: Please take a look at this example: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/6f3b5b7ad8bf46fe05a7f25e626513ba?editors=1000